# Position of node misplaced in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the plot of a parabola.  Its vertex `(2,16)` is grossly misplaced.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=3in,width=3in, clip=false,
xmin=-4,xmax=8,
ymin=-12,ymax=22,
restrict y to domain=-12:22,
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xtick={-2},ytick={16},
xticklabel style={font=\tiny, fill=white, below right},
xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}{2}},
extra x ticks={6},
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={below left}},
extra x tick labels={6},
enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={latex-latex},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=-3:7, blue] {-x^2 + 4*x + 12} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize]{$y = -x^{2} + 4x + 12$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, domain=-10:20] (2,x) node [pos=0.10, anchor=north, font=\tiny, sloped]{$x=2$};
\draw[fill] (2,16) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\node[anchor=225, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(2,16) +(45:0.15)$){$(2,16)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing the `calc` library from your code by the way.

Comment: @Adelyn: If you use `\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize] at (2,16) {$(2,16)$};`, the node is nicely positioned.

Comment: @Jake  Why doesn't `anchor=225` give the same positioning as `anchor=south west`?

Comment: Do you have special reason to calculate node position on so complicated way? Try, if `\node[above right,font=\footnotesize] at (2,16) {$(2,16)$};` gives what you like to obtain.

Comment: @Adelyn Because nodes are rectangular, I think.

Comment: @Zarko  That does give me the proper positioning for `(2,16)`.  Though, I would use `above right `0.15cm`.   Just to be consistent with code that I use for other `TikZ` environments, I wanted to use something like what I had in my post.  Why doesn't `anchor=225` give me the same positioning as the command you suggested?

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Are you saying that since the width of the node is much bigger than the height, `anchor=225` is not where I expect it is?

Comment: Yes, precisely that. Try for example `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (a) {aaa};
\fill  (a.south west) circle[radius=1pt];
\fill  [red] (a.225) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: To see, where is anchor at angle 225, try `\node (x) [draw,anchor=225] at (2,16) {$(2,16)$}; \draw[red] (x.center) -- (225:3); `

Comment: Look up the `axis direction cs:` in the `pgfplots` documentation: `\node[font=\footnotesize,above right] at ($(2,16)+(axis direction cs: 0.15*cos 45, 0.15*sin 45)$) {$(2,16)$};` Though, I'd just use `\node[font=\footnotesize, above right] at (2,16) {$(2,16)$};`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Not the problem, with `compat=1.11` that is the default.

Comment: @Zarko  Yes, between the comments from you and `Torbjørn T.`, I recall this description in the `pgfplots` manual.  Thanks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Right, though the `(45:015)` throughts `pgfplots` out of the loop. One would need the `axis direction cs` then. (I edited my comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's going on exactly, but I also don't quite understand why you go through all that trouble to add a label like that. Why not just do

```
\draw[fill] (2,16) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above right,font=\footnotesize]{$(2,16)$};
```

---

`pgfplots` rescales all data by default, and this appears to cause some conflict with coordinate calculations such as the one you tried. If you add `disabledatascaling` to the axis options your code works as expected though.

Complete examples below. I added all the settings to a style just to shorten the code and highlight the difference.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{adelyndefaults/.style={
height=3in,width=3in, clip=false,
xmin=-4,xmax=8,
ymin=-12,ymax=22,
restrict y to domain=-12:22,
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xtick={-2},ytick={16},
xticklabel style={font=\tiny, fill=white, below right},
xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}{2}},
extra x ticks={6},
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={below left}},
extra x tick labels={6},
enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={latex-latex},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
adelyndefaults,
]

\addplot[samples=21, domain=-3:7, blue] {-x^2 + 4*x + 12} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize]{$y = -x^{2} + 4x + 12$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, domain=-10:20] (2,x) node [pos=0.10, anchor=north, font=\tiny, sloped]{$x=2$};
\draw[fill] (2,16) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above right,font=\footnotesize]{$(2,16)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
adelyndefaults,
disabledatascaling
]

\addplot[samples=21, domain=-3:7, blue] {-x^2 + 4*x + 12} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize]{$y = -x^{2} + 4x + 12$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, domain=-10:20] (2,x) node [pos=0.10, anchor=north, font=\tiny, sloped]{$x=2$};

\node[anchor=225, inner sep=0,font=\footnotesize] at ($(axis cs:2,16) +(45:0.15)$){$(2,16)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added the `calc` package to the preamble.  Yes, your code is more efficient ... but now I am curious why the `node` command that I issued is not typesetting `(2,16)` in the appropriate place.

Comment: @Adelyn I'm guessing it has something to do with how `calc` parses axis coordinates. Another detail: You don't need 501 samples for that plot, it only adds compilation time and not much detail. 51 for example, is enough.

Comment: I saw your use of `disabledatascaling` as an option for the `axis` environment.  Yes, this does give me the display that I was expecting.  Instead of bothering to remember this detail of coordinate calculations by `pgfplots`, I will use Zarko's suggestion of `above right=0.15cm, inner sep=0`.

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{yunit = 0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(6.85,17.8)
  \psaxes[ticks = none, labels = none]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-2)(6.5,17)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplot[algebraic, linecolor = blue]{-2.2}{6.2}{-x^2+4*x+12}
  \uput[300](-2,0){$-2$}
  \uput[240](6,0){$6$}
  \psline[linestyle = dashed](0,16)(2,16)(2,0)
  \uput[270](2,0){$2$}
  \uput[180](0,16){$16$}
  \psdot(2,16)
  \uput[90](2,16){$(2,16)$}
  \rput(3.7,7){\textcolor{blue}{$-x^{2} + 4x + 12$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]